# Vertically center align a text on the right side of an image in a div

Tags: html, css

I have a bunch of image and text side by side, both are inside a div that is `float:right`. [This is how it looks now](https://imgur.com/a/ywAaX). I need to vertically center align the text beside the image (for example `Text Answer`). How do I do that? Please suggest.

```
<div id="content">Content here</div>
        <div id="navbar">
          <br>
          <div id ="quesBuilderText">Question Builder</div> <br>
          <div id = "textImage"> <img id="textImg"/></div>
          <div id = "textText"> Text Answers </div>
          <br> <br> <br>
          <div id = "multipleChoiceImage"> <img id="multipleChoiceImg"/></div>
          <div id = "multipleChoiceText"> Multiple Choice </div>
          <br> <br> <br>
          <div id = "dropdownImage"> <img id="dropdownImg"/></div>
          <div id = "dropdownText"> Dropdown </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Sample CSS

```
#navbar {
  float: right;
  width: 24%;
  background-color: white;
}
#textImg {
  width:30%;
  max-width: 40px;
  height:auto;
  margin-left: 20px;
  float: left;
}

#textText {
  margin-left: 10px;
  float: left;
  color: #7F7F7F;
}
```

Comment: On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, a
nd Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows. The essential part is the CSS rule for `#navbar>div` , but note that I deleted a lot of the other settings and added a class `.textText` to all three texts (instead of IDs):

```css
#navbar {
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
}

.textText {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#quesBuilderText {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#navbar>div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">Content here</div>
<div id="navbar">
  <br>
  <div id="quesBuilderText">Question Builder</div> <br>
  <div id="textImage"> <img src="http://placehold.it/40x30/fb7" id="textImg" /></div>
  <div class="textText"> Text Answers </div>
  <br> <br> <br>
  <div id="multipleChoiceImage"> <img src="http://placehold.it/40x30/fb7" id="multipleChoiceImg" /></div>
  <div class="textText"> Multiple Choice </div>
  <br> <br> <br>
  <div id="dropdownImage"> <img src="http://placehold.it/40x30/fb7" id="dropdownImg" /></div>
  <div class="textText"> Dropdown </div>
</div>
```